# zoom animation using animation with block based methods

Tags: ipad, ios4, core-animation, zooming

I have a zoom animation in which when I perform an action, a view comes up in a zooming fashion.

The code I use to do this is,

```
            CGFloat xpos = self.view.frame.origin.x;
    CGFloat ypos = self.view.frame.origin.y;
    popContents.view.frame = CGRectMake(xpos+100,ypos+150,5,5);
    [UIView beginAnimations:@"Zoom" context:NULL];
    [UIView setAnimationDuration:0.8];
    popContents.view.frame = CGRectMake(320, ypos-70, 350, 350);
    [UIView commitAnimations];
    [self.view.superview addSubview:popContents.view];
```

I just realized that in ios4.0 usage in this fashion is not recommended and animations using block based methods is recommended..

I tried looking for any sort of example which would give me a hint to get the zooming effect I need using the block based methods but I have not been able to find any...

It would be great if anyone could help me out in this...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i figured it out...

Apparently "zoom" is just a name and does not do anything( as far as I experimented with it)

Here is how I achieve the effect using animate with block based methods...

```
[UIView animateWithDuration:0.8 animations:^ { popContents.view.frame = CGRectMake(160, 70, 350, 350);
        [self.view.superview bringSubviewToFront:self.view];
        [self.view.superview addSubview:popContents.view]; }
                     completion: ^(BOOL finished) {
                         NSLog(@"DONE");
                     }
     ];
```

Now there is just 1 issue I am not able to figure out..

Here is the edited code -

```
[UIView transitionWithView:self.view duration:1 
                        options:UIViewAnimationOptionTransitionFlipFromLeft 
                     animations:^
                                { 
                                    popContents.view.frame = CGRectMake(160, 70, 350, 350);
                                    [self.view.superview bringSubviewToFront:self.view];
                                    [self.view.superview addSubview:popContents.view];
                                }
                     completion: ^(BOOL finished) 
                                {
                                    NSLog(@"DONE");
                                }];
```

so what happens here is that the table view rotates while the popContents view zooms to position.. I understand that is what will happen since I had given `transitionWithView:self.view`

however, how will I be able to add this effect to the popContents view ( the view which zooms to position)... is it possible?

I tried `transitionWithView:popContents.view` but that does not seem to have any additional effect to the zooming animation.

Could someone tell me what I am doing wrong?